# How to show values in html coming from object consistently?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

My html :

```
<p ng-repeat="gg in john(z.items)">Item:{{gg.name}}  Quantity:{{gg.quantity}}</p>
```

My controller:

```
 $http.get('/api/restros/myorders').success(function(val){
      console.log("my orders:");
      console.log(val);
      var temp=[];
      $scope.mydata=val;
      $http.get('/api/restros/').success(function(data){
        $scope.john=function(parent){
          console.log("parent");
          console.log(parent);
          for(var i=0;i<parent.length;i++){
            temp=[];
            for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
              if(data[j]._id==parent[i].id){
                temp.push([{name:data[j].name,quantity:parent[i].quantity,rate:data[j].rate}]);
              }
            }
              console.log(typeof (temp[0]));
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Now I want to show the response in the console like so:

Object: `{name: "Beef Burger", quantity: 1, rate: 150}`

Object: `{name: "Maharaja Mac", quantity: 1, rate: 150}`

Comment: why do you not use angular's ng-repeat ?

Comment: Z.items are the items which I want to parse and they are coming from the API provided to me from my company.

Comment: @simon I am using that only.

Answer (score 0):

Z.items are the items which I want to parse and they are coming from the API provided to me from my company.